# How can I get rid of the gap at the edge of the page?

Tags: css, html

I already set the border, padding and margin to 0px for the body and two of my divs. But I still can't seem to get rid of the gap.

```
#body{
 padding: 0px ;
 border:0px ; 
margin:0px;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
}


#mainPage {
height:100vh;
width:100%;
background-color: #2469ff;
padding: 0px;
border:0px; 
margin:0px;
}

#navBar{

height:70px; 
width:100%;
Background-color: #1f1f1f;  
padding: 0px ;
border:0px ; 
margin:0px;
}
```

That's all my CSS so far.

Here is my HTML. It's very basic at the moment.

```
<html>  
     <head>    
     <title>
     Ice Arena
     </title>          
     </head>    
     <body>       
          <div id="mainPage">       
              <div id="navBar">      
              </div>  
              <div id="leftPanel">      
              </div>   
          </div>    
     </body>
</html>
```

As I said, I don't know why it's doing this. I'm sure I made a mistake, I'm still a beginner with CSS and HTML.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please post your `html` codes as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS `margin` reset:

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Snippet below:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#body {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#mainPage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2469ff;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#navBar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  Background-color: #1f1f1f;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainPage">
    <div id="navBar">
    </div>
    <div id="leftPanel">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following to remove the default margin from `body`:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

### I strongly suggest you read this:

> #### [Default CSS Values for HTML Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)
>
> Default CSS Values for `body`  [ display: block; margin: 8px;]

```css
#body {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#mainPage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2469ff;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#navBar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  Background-color: #1f1f1f;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Ice Arena
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mainPage">
    <div id="navBar">
    </div>
    <div id="leftPanel">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. this worked. in future if i have this problem. will it always be the margin?

Comment: @Musty take 5mins to read this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp, body have a 8px margin by default.

Answer (score 2):

Make the Div CSS parameter as below:

`margin: 0 auto;`

This will center your margin.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this issue is very simple. Just remove the hashtag (#) from the 'body' like this:

```
    body{.....}
```

There is no need to ever use hashtags for unique HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

Add the html and body styling.

```
html, body{
 padding: 0px ;
 border:0px ; 
 margin:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the # from #body in your CSS.

Your CSS should be...

```
body{
padding: 0px ;
border:0px ; 
margin:0px;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
}
```